# Is there really no mremap in Darwin?

Tags: c, macos, mmap, memory-mapped-files, libc

I'm trying to find out how to remap memory-mapped files on a Mac (when I want to expand the available space).

I see our friends in the Linux world have `mremap` but I can find no such function in the headers on my Mac. `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/sys/mman.h` has the following:

- `mmap`
- `mprotect`
- `msync`
- `munlock`
- `munmap`
- but no `mremap`

`man mremap` confirms my fears.

I'm currently having to `munmap` and `mmmap` if I want to resize the size of the mapped file, which involves invalidating all the loaded pages. There must be a better way. Surely?

I'm trying to write code that will work on Mac OS X and Linux. I could settle for a macro to use the best function in each case if I *had* to but I'd rather do it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ftruncate the file to a large size (creating a hole) and mmap all of it. If the file is persistent I recommend filling the hole with write calls rather than by writing in the mapping, as otherwise the file's blocks may get unnecessarily fragmented on the disk.

Comment: So you're suggesting I should allocate for the largest possible size I could ever want and fill up the hole? It's an interesting idea but either I map the maximum possible range of addresses and leave no more addresses for anything else or I use a smaller amount and run the risk of running out. Also, this wouldn't be cross-platform (as indicated in my question) as I couldn't guarantee some filesystem wouldn't actually zero the whole range of the file and waste gigabytes.

Comment: You don't even need to make the file on disk that large. Just `mmap` larger than the file size. Accesses past the end of the file will result in `SIGBUS`, so you need to `ftruncate` it longer before trying to access new parts via the `mmap`, but otherwise it's fine.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE you sure that works on Darwin? POSIX requires doing mmap again after growing with ftruncate

Comment: @osvein: Oh, indeed it's unspecified what happens. `MAP_FIXED` of the part newly created with `ftruncate` should work though.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to shrink the map, just `munmap` the part at the end you want to remove.

<strike>If you need to enlarge the map, you can `mmap` the proper offset with `MAP_FIXED` to the addresses just above the old map, but you need to be careful that you don't map over something else that's already there...</strike>

The above text under strikeout is an awful idea; `MAP_FIXED` is fundamentally wrong unless you already know what's at the target address and want to atomically replace it. If you are trying to opportunistically map something new if the address range is free, you need to use `mmap` with a requested address but *without* `MAP_FIXED` and see if it succeeds and gives you the requested address; if it succeeds but with a different address you'll want to unmap the new mapping you just created and assume that allocation at the requested address was not possible.

Comment: Doesn't adding an extra mapped region run the risk of not being able to assign at that address?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was warning about. But I believe `MAP_FIXED` will always map over top of an existing mapping (destroying the existing mapping) rather than failing, which is even worse.

Answer (score 1):

If you expand in large enough chunks (say, 64 MB, but it depends on how fast it grows) then the cost of invalidating the old map is negligible. As always, benchmark before assuming a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with memory mapping, but it looks like you can temporarily map the same file twice as a means to expand the mapping without losing anything.

```
int main() {
    int fd;
    char *fp, *fp2, *pen;

      /* create 1K file */
    fd = open( "mmap_data.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0777 );
    lseek( fd, 1000, SEEK_SET );
    write( fd, "a", 1 );

      /* map and populate it */
    fp = mmap( NULL, 1000, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0 );
    pen = memset( fp, 'x', 1000 );

      /* expand to 8K and establish overlapping mapping */
    lseek( fd, 8000, SEEK_SET );
    write( fd, "b", 1 );
    fp2 = mmap( NULL, 7000, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0 );

      /* demonstrate that mappings alias */
    *fp = 'z';
    printf( "%c ", *fp2 );

      /* eliminate first mapping */
    munmap( fp, 1000 );

      /* populate second mapping */
    pen = memset( fp2+10, 'y', 7000 );

      /* wrap up */
    munmap( fp2, 7000 );
    close( fd );
    printf( "%d\n", errno );
}
```

The output is `zxxxxxxxxxyyyyyy....`.

I suppose, if you pound on this, it may be possible to run out of address space faster than with `mremap`. But nothing is guaranteed either way and it might on the other hand be just as safe.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't this cause a lot of extra IO over mmap MAP_PRIVATE and mremap? Due to MAP_SHARED flushing writes to disk?

Comment: @Eloff: Only way is to try and see. This post is very old and I never had much incentive to perform the experiment :vP . It would be a bit surprising to see excessive flushes, since all the memory is always mapped at least once. The OS should only flush when the last mapping is eliminated, right?